# Java - get number of days between dates

Tags: java, date

I've got a list of dates in format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, I'd like to have a number of days between my today date "2017-04-15" and first date from list which is higher than mine today date.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: please read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Probably not even search.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: What doesn't work in the code that you have shown?

Comment: can you try my answer?

Comment: if you have your events as Date

Comment: This is one of the things that have become so much easier with the `java.time` classes introduced in Java 8 (and backported to Java 6 and 7).

Comment: Hint: Search for `java.time.LocalDate` and `ChronoUnit.DAYS`. Already asked and answered many many times over on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your events are *not* sorted by date. I am assuming that you can use Java 8. This is one of the tasks that have become so much easier with the `java.time` classes introduced in Java 8 (and backported to Java 6 and 7).

Use `LocalDate.now()` to get today’s date.

Iterate through your events, all the time keeping track of the closest future event date. For each event use `LocalDate.parse()` to convert the event’s date to a `LocalDate`. The 1-arg `parse` method fits your format. Compare with today’s date and with the earliest future event date encountered so far; if between, store as the new closest date. Use `isAfter()` and/or `isBefore` for the comparisons.

After your loop, you will either know the date or you will know that there are no future events at all. In the former case, use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` to get the number of days from the current date to the event date.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

If you are using [**joda library**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html), then it will be easy, you can use [**`Days.daysBetween`**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial))  :

```
Date startDate = ...;
Date endDate = ...;

int nbrDays = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(startDate), new LocalDate(endDate)).getDays();
```

---

**Solution 2**

```
Date startDate = ...;
Date endDate = ...;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
int day1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

cal.setTime(endDate);
int day2 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int nbrDays = day1 - day2;
System.out.println(nbrDays);
```

You have to import :

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

---

**Solution 3**

If your dates are in this format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` so you can have two dates like this :

```
String date1 = "1991-07-03";
String date2 = "2017-04-15";
```

What you should to do, split your dates with `-` :

```
String spl1[] = date1.split("-");
String spl2[] = date2.split("-");
```

Calculate the difference between the two dates :

```
int year1  = Integer.parseInt(spl1[0]);
int month1 = Integer.parseInt(spl1[1]);
int days1  = Integer.parseInt(spl1[2]);

int year2  = Integer.parseInt(spl2[0]);
int month2 = Integer.parseInt(spl2[1]);
int days2  = Integer.parseInt(spl2[2]);
```

//make some calculation and in the end you can get the diffidence, this work i will let it for you.

Comment: Should I import Days ?

Comment: you have to download the library the joda library, you can easily find it in good

Comment: I can't I've to do that without downloading any library, I can import only

Comment: @stackish then you can check my second solution, you have to import `java.util.Calendar;
and java.util.Date;` library

Comment: @stackish check the 3rd solution  this can gives you an idea also

Comment: Option 4: `ChronoUnit#between`

Comment: yes @RobinTopper exactly i want to put it but i'm lazy haha, in fact there are many ways thank you any way :)

Comment: I’ve read that JodaTime is now in maintenance mode and that you should prefer to use `java.time`. If you aren’t using Java 8 or later yet, you can get them in the [ThreeTen Backport (follow the link)](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
        SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
        try {
            beforeDate = myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-13");
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-10"));
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-11"));
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-12"));
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-19"));
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-20"));
            dateList.add(myDateFormat.parse("2016-01-21"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //add here
        boolean check = true;
        for(int i = 0; check && i < dateList.size();i++){
            if(dateList.get(i).after(beforeDate)){
                afterDate = dateList.get(i);
                check = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(beforeDate+" "+afterDate);
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(myDateFormat.format(beforeDate)), LocalDate.parse(myDateFormat.format(afterDate)));
        if(days>0){
            System.out.println(days);
        }else{
            System.out.println(0-days);
        }
```

if you want to sort dateList then want to get afterDate then use this code after addition of date elements in dateList

```
Collections.sort(dateList,new Comparator<Date>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
```

This will allow you to sort dates in ascending order..

Comment: for more info about that class visit here :: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-

Comment: If you can use `LocalDate` and `ChronoUnit`, this is certainly a good idea. In this case, you will want to avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` altoghether and only use the newer classes. And thanks for the link in the comment.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for info. My hand moved with SimpleDateFormat as i got used for it sure will replace that part. Thanks for comment.